# How to create a stand-alone, plain javascript minified version of the capacitor-community http module example

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify

All I want is to take the example source code under Usage at https://github.com/capacitor-community/http and compile a standalone javascript file I can include in my app. I have already done `npm install @capacitor-community/http` and I do have a working CapacitorJS app.

I have tried `browserify`, and I get:

```
$ browserify test.js -o out.js

test.js:2
import '@capacitor-community/http';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

I have tried `esbuild` and I get:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/esbuild test.js --bundle --outfile=out.js
 > test.js:12:20: error: Expected ";" but found "Http"
    12 │   const ret = await Http.request({
       ╵                     ~~~~

1 error
```

My project is plain javascript, so I don't have a build pipeline set up (nor do I know how to do such a thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the CLI version of Babel to do this.

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli

Try running

```
npx babel test.js --out-file out.js
```

Comment: Doing that, I get the following error:

{ SyntaxError: test.js: Unexpected reserved word 'await' (12:14)

  10 |   const { Http } = Plugins;
  11 |
> 12 |   const ret = await Http.request({
     |               ^
  13 |     method: 'GET',
  14 |     url: 'https://example.com/my/api',
  15 |     headers: {

Comment: I expect your going to have to install Babel locally then and set it up to uses some plugins that support things like `await`. You should find everything you need in https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env